# ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

Tags: pandas

I got this error when trying to reindex a dataframe, e.g.

```
df = df.reindex(index=index_list,columns=column_list)
```

I know what this error means however the dataframe `df` doesn't have any duplicated index or column names when I check value_counts on index and column names. The `index_list` and `column_list` used for reindex also don't have any duplicates. Any ideas what else I could check the duplicated index? Thank you.

Comment: You're suggesting that pandas has a bug? It's not likely. When I get in to those situations I challenge my assumptions as it's most likely I made a mistake and my data isn't what I think, or my code isn't what I think. As you included *neither* in your question, there's nothing for us to help with. (Please read [mre] and [ask].)

Comment: Hi, that's not what I'm suggesting. I'm saying that I can't identify the duplicates this way, and asking if there is something missing or if I should check it differently?

Comment: Please ***read*** [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the dataframe df doesn't have any duplicated index or column names.

**Yes it does** or at least it should. Suppose the following example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6, 3)),
                      index=[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

          A         B         C
0  0.861939  0.443634  0.380200
1  0.922506  0.294640  0.987373
2  0.734945  0.417721  0.633269  # dupe
2  0.786877  0.010366  0.440029  # dupe
3  0.050342  0.991288  0.010531
4  0.499938  0.210002  0.939119

index_list = np.arange(0, 6)
column_list = list('XYZ')
```

Your code raised the right exception because the source index contains duplicates:

```
>>> df.reindex(index=index_list, columns=column_list)
...
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

To find them, using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html) on `Index` is right:

```
>>> df.index.value_counts()
2    2  # dupe
0    1
1    1
3    1
4    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

>>> df.columns.value_counts()
A    1
B    1
C    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

You can also use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) on `Index`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index.duplicated(keep=False), df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]
Empty DataFrame  # because one axis does not contain any dupe
Columns: []
Index: [2, 2]  # list of duplicated
```

Now, a little clarification about [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). Suppose you don't have a dupe, reindexing a dataframe means that if the new index/column does not exist in the source dataframe, some rows/columns will be inserted with `NaN` values.

There are other cases. If your `index_list`/`column_list`:

- contains duplicates, some rows/columns will be duplicated,
- contains less values than your original index/column, you get a subset of your source dataframe,
- contains same values but in the different order, your final dataframe will be reordered.

However, if you want to set new index/columns labels, maybe you should use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) (it implies that `len(df.columns) == len(column_list)` and/or `len(df.index) == len(index_list)`):

```
>>> df.set_axis(index_list, axis=0).set_axis(column_list, axis=1)
          X         Y         Z
0  0.861939  0.443634  0.380200
1  0.922506  0.294640  0.987373
2  0.734945  0.417721  0.633269
3  0.786877  0.010366  0.440029
4  0.050342  0.991288  0.010531
5  0.499938  0.210002  0.939119
```